# XCode can't link class of Table View

Tags: xcode, uitableview, class

I made a new controller with sub-class UITableViewController.

[image]

I don't have option to add custom class of feedController.swift. If I do that manually it crashes. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What does the exception message say when it crashes?

Comment: Is your `tableController.swift` a subclass of `UITableViewController`? If not, then it won't be recognized by your table view controller in Interface Builder as shown in your screenshot.